# How to add two arrays of different shapes in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, multidimensional-array

I do have two arrays one with the shape of (160,1400,1200) and another with the shape of (160,1400,3). I am trying to create two new arrays that will combine these arrays, one output array column wise and one output array row wise.

Comment: can you give an explicit input/output example with unambiguous arrays of a smaller size? (let's say (2,3,12) and (2,3,3))

Answer (score 0):

Use `numpy.concatenate()` to combine these.

```
numpy.concatenate((a1, a2, ...), axis=0, out=None, dtype=None, casting="same_kind")
```

In your case,

```
import numpy as np

# First
a1 = np.random.rand(160, 1400, 1200)

# Second
a2 = np.random.rand(160, 1400, 3)
```

Concatenate the arrays column-wise

```
column_wise_array = np.concatenate((a1, a2), axis=2)
```

Concatenate the arrays row-wise

```
row_wise_array = np.concatenate((a1, a2), axis=1)
```

> Here is the more information in [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) about `numpy.concatenate`